Is pydantic useful for creating template based frontend using Jinja2 with FastAPI?
Question:
I started creating an app using FastAPI and Jinja2, and faced the problem that for me it seems like these 2 are not really cool together in context of creating something bigger than a todo app.
FastAPI with its Pydantic features seems to be perfect for modern apps which use frameworks like React for frontend, but is there any use of Pydantic for templates?
Details:
For example, after retrieving a model from my database, I need to validate some of my model fields in order to display them properly on frontend, and there are 2 ways to do this I came up with:

Create a dictionary in python which is going to hold a key of an model attribute and value as prepared attribute value (when saying prepared I mean that I want to apply strftime to some datetime field, check if values are not None if I need to multiply them, etc.)
Create similar dictionary but in a Jinja2 template, which is going to fulfill the same function, but using Jinjas filters.

Both of these ways have their cons, because as for a backend part, I do not want to lose this easiness and clean look of endpoints and create massive dictionaries there, I want to just return models from my DB and pass them to a template, but the second way does not look good either, as I have heard, putting any logic to the frontend is a bad practice.
As for the second variant which I currently decided to stick with, it looks something like this:
{% set service_enforcement_fields = {
    'beginnt am': service_enforcement.start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if service_enforcement.start_date else '',
    'Preis pro Teilnehmer': '{} €/Teilnehmer'.format(service_enforcement.price_per_participant),
    'Gesamtkosten': '{} €'.format(service_enforcement.price_flat + (service_enforcement.price_per_unit * service_enforcement.amount) + (service_enforcement.price_per_participant * service_enforcement.number_of_participants)),
    'abgerechnet am': service_enforcement.final_billing.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if service_enforcement.final_billing else '',
    'bearbeitet von': service_enforcement.last_edit_user.login,
} %}

After creating this dictionary I display it with a for loop with adding of some filters to each element.
It seems like I could have reached some similar result using Pydantic, and pass the schema to the template, but is it a case?
I am sorry if question is not perfect, its my first one here, I would also be grateful for any links on real world projects which use FastAPI and Jinja2 to have a refference.

Or you can use jinja2 filters instead, and avoid having to create dictionaries (or Pydantic models) just to hold the values to print (gesamtkosten which have business logic could also probably be part of your sqlalchemy model as a @property or a service layer - and not part of your template logic.

@MatsLindh thank you for your comment. Actually doing this using jinja filters is what I am trying to achieve, however, i need to iterate not through all of the fields of the model (which is the first reason I decided to use dict like this). Also, just iterating through it would cause problems with dealing with different data types, as datetime requires different treatment (actually I just thought about some type checks in jinja, not sure if its the case).

My experience is that as long as you know which fields to display, it's usually better to be explicit instead of looping over the dict; looping over the dict is fine when you need to output all values for some specific reason (debug log/etc. where the number of fields necessary is unknown). But you can use isinstance-checks to determine if you use a modifier to format a date or not for example

@MatsLindh I actually thought that specifying the dictionary is better in order to avoid code repetition (I need to display like 25 fields, and I moved from repeating 25 rows of same  tags to the dict so that I can just loop, and maybe even create a macro for that in the future, as I have several models which need to be displayed alike). Also as far as I know there is no is instance method available in Jinja, if thats what you meant.

You can make your own test - or you can make a modifier that either returns a string if it is one, or formats it in a locale specific format if it's a datetime. It'll also be more simplified when you get the logic moved out from your template - that way you can effectively just define a list of attributes that you want rendered from a specific row, and then iterate over those instead.

@MatsLindh I am going to try that, thanks a lot!
